# What am I doing wrong with the Ipute File in React.js Node.js and Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, file

from frontend
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8UmB.jpg

from Service

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbH2K.jpg

form Server

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yCZt.jpg

the Error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QlIM.jpg

Comment: paste code as text not pics , please

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading file with name of **video** in formData and fetching with req.file only on server side you will get file on server like this

```
if(!(req.files && req.files.video)) // return error
const file = req.files.video;
```

Comment: is throw Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

Comment: It gives me that !!!


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOWT1.jpg

Comment: check with postman and also let me know what did tou change in your backend code.

Comment: This postman backend and mongodb IS WORKING but When I do all the with frontend is not seving the video in uploads file          https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0C5a.jpg